# Binding a list of controls to a canvas

Tags: wpf, binding, canvas

Is it possible to bind an OvservableCollection of Labels or and FrameworkElement to a canvas?
If so how can this be implemented?

Comment: what do you mean by "bind"? you want these items to be children? or you want them to "share" some properties? or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an ItemsControl and set its ItemsPanel property to a Canvas:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource={Binding Items}>
  <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <Canvas/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

Hope this help